# flutter project doesn't has app level build gradle dependencies section

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

Flutter project does not has dependencies section in app level build gradle and i can not add it manually because it doesn't show's any suggestion either

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
```

Comment: it doesnt need one at its bare minimum, you should add it if you are adding any dependencies

Comment: it doesn't suggests either when i start typing. Instead it suggets for other things starting with de words such as default etc is there a problem or no ?

Comment: i wanted to add firebase dependencies

Comment: Not all firebase products use gradle dependencies I think. Just analytics and crashlytics. You can check out this: https://fireship.io/snippets/install-flutterfire/

Comment: it doesnt suggest because the project is of flutter type not bare android project, i really dont know why the gradle linting in flutter doesnt work correctly, it even throws errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your dependencies under this.

```
 flutter {
   source '../..'
 }
```

like this:

```
flutter {
   source '../..'
 }

dependencies {
  // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
  implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0"
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-marketing:[4,5)' 
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:7.0.2'
 }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```